# DNN Portal website not showing up and only downloading a document file

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetnuke, dnn9

We have a DNN based websites being used for our company. Within that there are multiple sites among which there is a site at *https://example.com/siteId25*.
This particular site have been modified by any one of the Admin's in such a way that upon visiting that url, its only downloading a document(.docx) file rather then showing the website which used to be there.

The file is within the hosted website's portal folder at path *"wwroot/WebsiteFolder/Portal/25/Info siteId25.docx"*. Upon removing that file, it starts giving error.

We already have Testing version of that site on a different server, which is serving appropriate website page upon visiting that path.
Upon checking the Site settings in the Website Persona Bar, as well as checking that in the database table `Portal Settings`, we didn't found any relevant settings to serve document rather then webpage.

All of the settings are having same values default values in both production & in Testing environment. We tries switching Site Alias mapping mode from canonical to direct, but issue persist.
Can anyone please tell us any to set back url to show website rather then download file?

Answer (score 0):

You find the start page in the table PortalLocalization. The value in the field HomeTabId is the TabId from the table Tabs (pages were called tabs in DNN in former times).

Mind the field PortalId, and CultureCode (if you have a multilingual portal). Set the value to the TabId needed (mind the PortalId also in the table Tabs).

After changing anything in the databse, you should always restart the application pool in IIS. If you have no other way to do it, just open the web.config file with a text editor, enter a blank line, delete this line and save the file.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't helps, I checked that table on both my Test Server as well as production server DB, all data for that portal ID is exactly same. Its not localization issue, the url is serving a word document rather then the website.

Comment: It is just some configuration issue in some table, as when I switch the DNN Site Connection String to the test server DB, then it starts serving that website at that page, but on production DB its serving that word document upon visiting that url

Comment: In this case you should inspect the field Url in the record in the Tabs table, If you find something like "FileId=x" (x is an integer that refers to the FileId in the Files table). Set the value of this field to NULL.